# Error trying to download NOOBS

Tags: noobs

I have been trying to download NOOBS. But the downloads keep failing. Not on my RPI. But on my computer. I've tried so many things. But it keeps failing. Is there another way i can download it?

Comment: Do you mean another way than that you haven't told us about? What errors?

Comment: What version? Lite or with Raspbian?

Comment: @anonymoose I am using the normal one found here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/

Comment: @Milliways I am just trying to download it. But when i download it it says it's corrupt

Comment: You are using the Download Zip option (as opposed to Download Torrent) aren't you? Download torrent would only work for you if your local OS has an app installed for p2p file sharing such as bittorrent etc. Otherwise it would only download a small ",torrent" file to your disk.

Comment: What is the exact filename of the file you download?

Comment: @MartinMarty Ok. I downloaded BitTorrent. And it works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the direct link 
[Noobs](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/NOOBS_latest) found on the "read me" file on Github [Git](https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs) or use Torrent